# Create Custom UITabBarController in which Label should be in front of Image not bottom

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to create the custom `UITabBarController` , the layout should looks like first the image then title infront of that image not the bottom of the image.

Please suggest me the way how to do that or any link that can guide me for the same

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [sample](https://github.com/alikaragoz/AKTabBarController)

Using this you can adjust the Title potion or whatever you want customization within `tabbar`. Hope this would be help.